# How to create an input dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

How can I create a dropdown for input with CSS or anything else?

For an example, see this image:

[image]

What do I do it?

Comment: take a look on the View Source for the `css` part

Comment: you can use jquery ui auto complete...

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at jQuery auto-complete -

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: i have a auto-complete, myself created. dont know how is dropdown for input it. please tell me about input dropdown ?